# Modify the steps of the x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot

The question is simple and I found some similar question around the web. But in my special case I can not get the point. ;)

See this example

```
df = data.frame(Year=c(2012,2013,2014), N=c(61175,52477,48699))
plot(df[,c('Year', 'N')], type='o')
```

The problem in this resulting plot-picture is the stepping on the x-axis. **e.g. I don't want "2012.5".**

[image: asdf]

Ok, I know that to draw the plot without a x-axis description.

```
plot(df[,c('Year', 'N')], xaxt='n', type='o')
```

But now I have the problem how to use `axis()` to add correct values there.
I tried a lot of variants.

```
axis(1, xaxp=c('2012','2013','2014'))
axis(1, 1:3, xaxp=c('2012','2013','2014'))
axis(1, 1:3, xaxp=df$Year)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
plot(df[,c('Year', 'N')], xaxt='n', type='o')
axis(1, at = df$Year, labels = df$Year)
```

[image]